# Why can't ssh run rbenv in the shell?

Tags: ssh, bash

I'm trying to run a bash script on a remote server to install ruby via rbenv.

```
#!/bin/bash
# ssh deploy@192.168.50.2 'bash -s' < configure.sh

echo "ruby 3.2.1"
rbenv install 3.2.1 --verbose
rbenv global 3.2.1
```

On a remote server `rbenv` is already installed for the user `deploy`. If I log into that server, it runs OK.

```
❯ ssh deploy@192.168.50.2
```

```
deploy@ubuntu-focal:~$ rbenv
rbenv 1.2.0-59-g0704e65
Usage: rbenv <command> [<args>...]
```

But if we try to run the command over ssh, it can't be found.

```
❯ ssh deploy@192.168.50.2 "rbenv"
bash: rbenv: command not found
```

Same problem with the script.

```
❯ ssh deploy@192.168.50.2 'bash -s' < configure.sh
ruby 3.2.1
bash: line 5: rbenv: command not found
bash: line 6: rbenv: command not found
bash: line 7: ruby: command not found
bash: line 9: gem: command not found
bash: line 10: gem: command not found
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, `$PATH` is not set.

Bash, when started in interactive mode or as login shell, reads a few config files, such as `.profile` and `.bashrc`:

> ```
> --noprofile
>   Do not read either the system-wide startup file /etc/profile  or
>   any   of  the  personal  initialization  files  ~/.bash_profile,
>   ~/.bash_login, or ~/.profile.   By  default,  bash  reads  these
>   files  when  it  is invoked as a login shell (see INVOCATION be-
>   low).
>
> --norc Do  not  read  and  execute  the  personal  initialization  file
>        ~/.bashrc if the shell is interactive.  This option is on by de-
>        fault if the shell is invoked as sh.
> ```

From `man bash`. You start a non-login, non-interactive shell.

Either, your script should:

1. `source ~/.bashrc`
2. Specify `$PATH` on it's own
3. Use absolute paths

Comment: Thank you @vidarlo, the `source` didn't work, but setting the `$PATH` did.